# How to change Picker background Color in Xamarin MAC Platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, monodevelop, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

After updating the Xamarin Library and MAC OS to latest system, facing issue in Picker Background color and color of item that is selected/focused in picker for MAC Platform in my visual studio 2017.

Picker that is filled with multiple values

[image: Here is the picture of Picker that is filled with multiple value]

On opening the picker can not able to set the background color and the item that is selected is also not visible because of its color

[image: On opening the picker can not able to set the background color and the item that is selected is also not visible because of its color.]

How can I set the background color of that picker and the color of that focused/selected item of picker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be caused for the new Theme used by Mojave.

One way to overcome this issue is by setting a value that will be visible on both Light and Dark them, for me it worked the Green.

Adding this to your XAML should be sufficient

```
<Picker.TextColor>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
        <On Platform="macOS" Value="Green"/>
    </OnPlatform>
</Picker.TextColor>
```

Making the change only on your MacOs project leaving the others as they are.

```
<Picker HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>Dell</x:String>
        <x:String>HP</x:String>
        <x:String>Mac</x:String>
        <x:String>Asus</x:String>
        <x:String>Lenovo</x:String>
        <x:String>Acer</x:String>
        <x:String>Micrsoft</x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
    <Picker.TextColor>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
            <On Platform="macOS" Value="Green"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Picker.TextColor>
</Picker>
```

Note: The `TextColor` will only affect the selected item text color.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: From v3.4 They have changed OnPlatform xaml now. It's `OnPlatform Android="foo" iOS="foo"` it just gives warning though

Comment: Yes this is the one and last option that i already think off if not have any solution.
Thank you for guidence.

Answer (score 0):

To change `BackGroundColor` of all `Picker` items for iOS you need to use custom renderer.

Your `Picker` in shared project

```
<StackLayout>
    <Picker x:Name="picCities" ></Picker>
</StackLayout>
```

In your  `ContentPage` cs file assign `ItemsSource` to `Picker`

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    picCities.ItemsSource = new List<string> { "Hyderabad", "Bhopal", "Indore", "Jabalpur", "Mumbai", "Ahmedabad" };
    picCities.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Now in your iOS project add one `.cs` file name `PickerCustomRenderer` & add this code

```
[assembly: ExportRendererAttribute(typeof(Picker), typeof(PickerCustomRenderer))]
namespace picker.iOS
{
    public class PickerCustomRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            UITextField textField = Control;
            UIPickerView pickerView = textField.InputView as UIPickerView;
            pickerView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I want to change the background color of the Items that are in Picker
When open the Picker the list get opened i want to change the color of that opened list
In Second Picture when i click on picker it opens the list of element is is in light blue color i want to change the background color of that list

Comment: According to your question heading you need to change background color. You can change picker bg color, picker text color(item text color). There is nothing like items color.

Comment: When open the Picker the list get opened i want to change the bakgroungcolor of that opened list
In Second Picture when i click on picker it opens the list of element it is in light blue color i want to change the background color of that list

Comment: @V-VekP-Tel - I have added screenshot in answer. Do you need picker like that?

Comment: Yes exactly i want to change the background color of the list for the picker
but picker i developed is a user defined control and that is for MAC OS

Comment: UITextField is component of UIKit that is supported in IOS.

I am not able to use same for MAC Platform

Comment: @V-VekP-Tel - Is this question about xamarin forms?

Comment: I have picker control in xamarin.forms and i made it custom renderer for MAC platform 
so for MAC i want to change the color. it was working fine before update of Xamarin library

Comment: I want to change the color of the item that is selected